# Flutter equivalent to Xamarin Forms Element AutomationID

Tags: flutter, xamarin

Does Flutter have an equivalent/alternative to the AutomationID available in Xamarin Forms xml?
I am currently running a Xamarin Forms application on an Android platform that uses the AutomationID to link voice commands to controls (button, edit, lists etc) on a page and wondered if a similar approach can be taken when using Flutter.
My searches did not come up with anything useful.
I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: In Flutter app level testing, `SerializableFinders` are used to find "widgets" (FYI: the base widgets are not "native" OS provided widgets, so normal automation ids are not available) : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction

Comment: @SushiHangover - thank you for the response, the link you provided is an interesting read!